# How to create an XML file from a GenericList<T> using LINQ using C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, using

```
class Program
{
    class Student
    {
        public int SID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Major { get; set; }
        public List<SubjGrade> SubjectGrades { get; set; }
    }

class SubjGrade
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public decimal grade { get; set; }
}
```

```
static List<Customer> LoadCustomers(string file) {}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var Students = LoadStudents(@"C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Students.txt");

    var studXML = 
        new XElement("Root",
                        from student in Students 
                        select new XElement("Student",
                                    new XElement("SID",student.SID),
                                    new XElement("Name",student.Name),
                                    new XElement("Major",student.Major)
                        // ????
                        // I cannot figure out how to create XElements
                        // for the SubjGrade list
                                            ) // end student
                    ); // end root
    Console.WriteLine(studXML);


    // this test works just fine but not what i am trying achive
    IEnumerable<Student> studs = from student in Students select student;
    foreach (var s in studs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}\t{2}", 
                s.SID.ToString(), s.Name, s.Major);
        Console.WriteLine("Class Cnt: {0}", 
                s.SubjectGrades.Count.ToString());
        foreach (var g in s.SubjectGrades)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", 
                    g.Subject, g.grade.ToString());        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot figure out how to get the subject and Grade items into the Student Element

Comment: Can you supply an example of how you want it to look?

Answer (score 3):

This would let you create multiple Grade elements below your Student element.

```
var studXML =
            new XElement("Root",
                            from student in Students
                            select new XElement("Student",
                                        new XElement("SID", student.SID),
                                        new XElement("Name", student.Name),
                                        new XElement("Major", student.Major),
                                        new XElement("Grades",
                                                    from subjectGrade in student.SubjectGrades
                                                    select new XElement("Grade",
                                                               new XElement("Subject", subjectGrade.Subject),
                                                               new XElement("Grade", subjectGrade.grade)))
                                                ) // end student
                        ); // end root
        Console.WriteLine(studXML);
```

Note that this doesn't safeguard against SubjectGrades being null.

Comment: I would probably put all  `<Grade>` elements inside one `<Grades>` to make the XML structure better. Also, I'm not sure it will even compile as it is now.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek very good point! I really should have written it out in Visual Studio first. I have edited my answer to include the <Grades> tag

Comment: thank you. i placed the following code and the results.

Comment: new XElement("Classes",
                    from subjectGrade in student.SubjectGrades
                    select new XElement("SubjGrade",subjectGrade.Subject,
                            new XAttribute("Grade", subjectGrade.grade)
                                        ) // end SubjGrade
                            ) // end Classes
                            ) // end student
                ); // end root

Comment: OUTPUT:
<Root>
  <Student>
    <SID>100</SID>
    <Name>John Smith</Name>
    <Major>English</Major>
    <Classes>
      <SubjGrade Grade="4.00">MTH100</SubjGrade>
      <SubjGrade Grade="3.00">ENG103</SubjGrade>
      <SubjGrade Grade="2.00">ART202</SubjGrade>
      <SubjGrade Grade="2.00">HIS110</SubjGrade>
      <SubjGrade Grade="3.50">CCS100</SubjGrade>
    </Classes>
  </Student>

Comment: You bring up the point about the situation where no grades for the student record. how would one address that?

Comment: added a where student.SubjectGrades.Count > 0 clause but it leaves   <Student> <SID>400</SID> <Name>Connie Martin</Name> <Major>Pyhsics</Major>
    <Classes />
  </Student>

Comment: The where clause would not be high enough, you would need to do something like (after the Major element) student.SubjectGrades != null && student.SubjectGrades.Count > 0 ? new XElement("Grades", ... as above) : null

Comment: Thank you all for your comments: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/32348/bijington
To address the situation where a student had no subj/grades, I added the where clause on s.SubjGrade.Count > 0 || s.SubjGrade != null
Then I played around with loading the students into a XDocument. This worked too. But I had to perform the extra step of iterating through xmlDoc,Descentants("Students") to an anonymous class before being able to post them to the console.

Thanks again.